# Android Calendar Event Add/Create Component

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api, android-contentprovider, android-calendar

All,

I am searching for an component i.e the Android Event creation/add screen in the calendar.The component looks like the one in the image below. No problem which ever the OS version it may be. I wanna achieve the way this standard android event screen can be called within an app.
iOS provides this kind of feature, does android also do?

Thanks, In advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Write the below code in your event Onclicklistner

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();              
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
        intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
        intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
        intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
        intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
        intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
        intent.putExtra("title", "A Test Event from android app");
        startActivity(intent);
```